# How to validate dynamic input field in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I am using `vuelidate` to validate input field, the input field is dynamic i.e the value in input field is filled dynamically with `jsonData` using `v-model`

**What I am trying to do is**

On blur I want to show error if there is any, but here when I type anything inside my input field it shows nothing

what I am doing:- my input field

```
    <div v-for="data in displayProfileData" :key="data.email" >
     <p>{{data}}</p>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <label for="phoneNo">Name</label>
              <input v-model="data.businessname"
              @blur="$v.form.name.$touch()"
              type="text" 
                            class="form-control" name="name"
                            id="name">
             <div v-if="$v.form.name.$error" class="form-error">
               <span v-if="!$v.form.name.required" class="text-danger">nameis required</span>
             </div>
                    </div>
          <p>{{$v}}</p>
   </div>
     </div>
```

I am displaying `$v` on UI to check but when I type in input field no changes is been detected

My script code :-

```
    <script>
import { required,minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import axios from '../../services/base-api'
export default {
    data (){
      return{
          form :{
        name:''
          },
           displayProfileData:[]
      }
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      name:{required}, 
    }
  },
  created(){
        this.userId = localStorage.getItem('user-Id')
        axios().post('/api/v1/Profile/getProfileData',this.userId)
        .then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data)
                this.displayProfileData=res.data

})
.catch(err=>{
    this.$toasted.error(err,{duration:2000})
})

}
}
</script>
```

My data from server is in format like this `{ "businessid": "8126815643", "businessname": "manish",}`

**Issue**
Initially when page loads in input field it shows `manish` so when I change it to something else and focus out it shows error that `name is required` I don't what is going wrong

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLRF7.png):[Dynamic Form- Check Here](http://simple-vue-validator.magictek.cn/#dynamic_form)

please check this [image]

Comment: You need to check this - [sub-collections-validation](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-collections-validation)

Comment: @sugars that didn't help as my input field values are dynamic,please check my code if you can help accordingly

Comment: Your `v-model` seems to be written like this, `v-model="$v.form.name.$model"` or `v-model="data.businessname.$model"`

Comment: @sugars No, if I use `v-model="$v.form.name.$model"` then my input field is empty which is not the case or if I use  `v-model="data.businessname.$model"` then also input field is empty and on typing throws error

Comment: All your inputs will have an id “**name”** in the v-for (I know it’s not what you are after, but I have to mention it)

Comment: @muka.gergely no will will have different id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [vuelidate's documentation](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-collections-validation), you should make the following changes:

```
<div v-for="data in $v.displayProfileData.$each.$iter" :key="data.email">
  ...
  <input  v-model="data.businessname.$model"
          @blur="data.businessname.$touch()"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          name="name"
          id="name"
  >
  <div v-if="data.businessname.$error" class="form-error">
     <span v-if="!data.businessname.required" class="text-danger">name is required</span>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

```
 validations: {
    displayProfileData: {
      //required,
      //minLength: minLength(1),
      $each: {
        businessname: { required }
      }
    }
 }
```

Attach my codesandbox example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-fvbug?fontsize=14)